# Django production with Apache in Ubuntu not show image

Tags: python, django, apache, webserver

I want to config my django project in Ubuntu server which use Apache but it  not show image. I edit file settings.py like this.

**settings.py**

```
DEBUG = False

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_URL='/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static','media')
```

I show image in html file like this.

**index.html**

```
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

        <img src="{% static '/media/images/logo.png' %}">

{% endblock %}
```

I set apache file in path /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
like this.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName myweb.com
        DocumentRoot /home/user/myproject_dir/myproject
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        Alias /static /home/user/myproject_dir/myproject/static
        <Directory /home/user/myproject_dir/myproject/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/user/myproject_dir/myproject/myproject>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        WSGIDaemonProcess myproject_dir python-path=/home/user/myproject_dir/myproject python-home=/home/user/myproject_dir/myproject_env
        WSGIProcessGroup myproject_dir
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/myproject_dir/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

I upload image to path like this.

```
/home/user/myproject_dir/myproject/static/media/images/logo.png
```

I use command collectstatic and restart apache service but it not show image in my website. How to fix it?

Comment: instead of just 'static' can you name to 'staticfiles'

Comment: You can see each request for an image as GET request in the Apache acces.log and check if the url is correct. You can also check in your browser the source code of your html and see if urls are correct. Just a hint how to debug.

Comment: Btw according to django philosophy media is for dynamically generated content like uploaded profile pictures etc. To be able to handle those items seperately I would not place media inside static but seperately